# use case tutorial

Tags: uml

Could you suggest a comprehensive use-case tutorial? I would like something which would explain how to organize use case diagrams in packages, relationships in UC diagrams.

Answer (score 5):

This is the best book I know about use cases.

[Writing Effective Uses Cases](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201702258)

Answer (score 4):

Yea.

> The best one is  in the book of Craig
>   Larman.(from Applying UML & Patterns )
>
> Do not forget the "Congratulations:
>   Use Cases are Written and Wrong (!)"
>   box.*

You can download it at  http://www.craiglarman.com/wiki/downloads/applying_uml/larman-ch6-applying-evolutionary-use-cases.pdf

And  finally a good paper

> Use Cases: Best Practices  By Ellen
>   Gottesdiener

Can be downloaded from http://ebgconsulting.com/Pubs/Articles/UseCaseBestPractices-Gottesdiener.pdf